# Docker compose service - recommended method to keep service running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm preparing some docker-compose.yml file with one service.

An example:

```
  service_test:
    image: image:latest
    volumes: 
      - /home/:/data
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM some_image:base as build
COPY . .

RUN chmod +x script.sh

ENTRYPOINT /script.sh
```

The script is runnig some process:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup example_process
sleep 10
```

So...
When I will build and run the docker-compose, the process work 10 seconds and after that of course container exits and closes the process.

I would like to leave the container running with working process there.

I'm not sure what is recommended to keep this process alive. (I mean good for system and security)

I have found for example that it's possible to add:

```
command: tail -f /dev/null
```

to the service or:

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

For me both where not working - cause in the Dockerfile I run some script using ENTRYPOINT.

I can add some infinity loop in my script.sh but yeah, still - not sure is it a good practice and is recommended.

Have a nice day and thank you for a help!

Comment: Assuming that your process is actually doing something, e.g. a web server process, and not just running some code and exiting? Depending on your use case of course, you could use supervisord to manage a constantly running process inside the container. And in you entrypoint you just run `supervisor -n` (or something like that, on top of my head).

Answer (score 0):

You should launch the single process you want to run as a foreground job.  Do not try to launch it in the background or use wrappers like `nohup`.  For this setup you don't even need the entrypoint script, just set the process to be the main container `CMD`.

```bash
FROM some_image:base as build
COPY . .
CMD example_process
```

As @babis21 notes in a comment, some processes are set up to run as a Unix daemon by default.  This requires extra coding to set up, so these processes typically have some option to run in the foreground, or not daemonize, or something similar.  You can include the option in the `CMD` line.

```bash
CMD example_process --no-daemonize
```

Popular open-source HTTP servers launch as daemons by default, so you can see these similar examples

```bash
# Apache
CMD httpd -DFOREGROUD
```

```bash
# Nginx
CMD nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```